# Adding and Removing Values from JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array of numbers. My array is defined like this:

```
var customerIds = [];
```

I have a function that is responsible for inserting and removing ids to/from this array. Basically, my function looks like this:

```
function addOrRemove(shouldAdd, customerId) {
  if (shouldAdd) {
    if (customerIds.contains(customerId) === false) {
      customerIds.push(customerId);
    }
  } else {
    customerIds.remove(customerId);
  }
}
```

This function is basically pseudocode. A JavaScript array does not have a contains or remove function. My question is, is there any elegant way of tackling this problem? The best I can come up with is always looping through the array myself and tracking the index of the first item found.

Thank you for any insights you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the Array method like below after that you are free to use 'contains' and 'remove'

```
if (!Array.contains)
    Array.prototype.contains = function(a) {
        for (var i in this) {
            if (this[i] == a) return true;
        }
        return false
    }
if (!Array.remove)
    Array.prototype.remove = function(a) {
        for (var i in this) {
            if (this[i] == a) {
                this.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this is a neat way to add the `contains` and `remove` function to the `Array.prototype`, @JQuery Mobile alluded to the idea of straying away from looping over the array for the answer. Both of these function which you've provided loop over the array until the proper index is located. For that matter, I think this answer should be reviewed before it is marked as accepted.

Comment: You should not iterate an array with `for..in`.

Comment: It is wierd to iterate an array with `for..in`, yet I'm not sure if I can see anything wrong with doing so, other than the fact that it doesnt feel right. The only difference between using `for..in` as apposed to `for(i=0;i<..;i++)` would be that your index reference would be in `String` format instead of `integer`

Answer (score 1):

1. The `contains` can be achieved with [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), like this

   ```
   if (customerIds.indexOf(customerId) === -1) {
   ```

   `indexOf` function returns `-1`, if it couldn't find the parameter in the array, otherwise the first index of the match. So, if the result is `-1`, it means that `customerIds` *doesn't contain* `customerId`.
2. The `remove` can be achieved with [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), like this

   ```
   var index = customerIds.indexOf(customerId);
   if (index !== -1) {
       customerIds.splice(index, 1);
   }
   ```

   Similarly, `indexOf` function returns `-1`, if it couldn't find the parameter in the array, otherwise the first index of the match. So, if the result is `-1`, we skip deleteing, otherwise `splice` `1` element starting from the position `index`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf` and `splice`

```
function addOrRemove(shouldAdd, customerId) {
    if (shouldAdd) {
        if (customerIds.indexOf(customerId) == -1) {
            customerIds.push(customerId);
        }
    } else {
        var index = customerIds.indexOf(customerId)
        customerIds.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely use the `splice` and `indexOf` as stated by @thefourtheye, yet I would like to provide another approach.

Instead of using an `array` you could use an `object`.

```
var customerIds = {};
//This could also be stated as: var customerIds = new Object(); this is just shorthand

function addOrRemove(shouldAdd, customerId)
{
    if(shouldAd)
    {
        if(!customerIds[customerId])
        {
            customerIds[customerId] = new Object();
            customerIds[customerId].enabled = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(customerIds[customerId])
        {
            customerIds[customerId].enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You now can query against the `customerIds` object for a specific `customerId`

```
if(customerIds[customerId].enabled)
```

Using this method not only provides you with the capability of attaching multiple attributes to a given `customerId`, but also allows you to keep records of all `customerIds` after disabling (removing).

Unfortunately, in order to truely remove the `customerId`, you would need to loop through the object and append each property of the object to a new object except for the one you do not want. The function would look like this:

```
function removeId(customerId)
{
    var n_customerIds = new Object();

    for(var key in customerIds)
    {
        if(key != customerId)
        {
            n_customerIds[key] = customerIds[key];
        }
    }

    customerIds = n_customerIds;
}
```

In no way am I stating that this would be the proper approach for your implementation, but I am just providing another method of achieving your goal. There are many equivalent ways to solve your dilemma, and it is solely decided by you which method will best suit your projects functionality. I have personally used this method in many projects, as well as I have used the methods posted by others in many other projects. Each method has their pros and cons.

If you do wish to use this method, I would only suggest doing so if you are not collecting many `customerIds` and do want a lot of `customerData` per each `customerId`, or, if you are collecting many `customerIds` and do not want a lot of `customerData` per each `customerId`. If you store a lot of `customerData` for a lot of `customerIds`, you will consume a very large amount of memory.